# connection profile not working after deployment-Birt Report

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, birt

I am using connection profiles for connecting to postgres database.After copying reports in tomcat,i am getting error(ie:"unable to determine the default workspace location.Check your OSG-iless platform configuration 
of the plugin or datatools workspace path") when tomcat starts.I am attaching screenshot of that error.Can anyone please help to figure out this issue..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the DTP Workspace.  Take a look at this wiki page:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Birt_3.7_Migration_Guide#Connection_Profiles

or you can download the osgi birt runtime.  You can find it on the full download page.  For example 4.2.2 is located here:
http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/build.php?build=R-R1-4_2_2-201302161152